# Is this is a singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, singleton

I was trying to write singleton class and initially i wrote the below code, which to me feels like singleton. I showed this to one of the guy and he immediately rejected it, So that kept me thinking why it is not a singleton class or was he wrong?

```
    let MyFunc = (function(){
       let instance;
       return function(){
           if(instance){
              return instance;
           }
           instance = this;
       } 
    }());
  let o1 = new MyFunc();
  let o2 = new MyFunc(); 
  console.log(o1===o2) //returns true
```

Comment: Why not *ask him* why he disagrees?

Comment: Well we can't know what he was looking for. If `o1 === o2` is the major requirement for something to be called "singleton" then you obviously wrote one.

Comment: having `new MyFunc()` always return the same instance is obsucre

Comment: As far as I can understand from the comments, it's more of a confusion than this not being singleton which makes sense since everytime you are calling class with "new" hoping that it will create a new but instead it returns singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't guess why that person disagreed. Certainly that code returns a single object regardless of the number of times you call it via `new`, and that object will get `MyFunc.prototype` as its prototype. So in that sense, it's a function that returns a singleton object.

There's not a lot of use for the singleton construction pattern in JavaScript (since we can create one-off objects directly), but that seems a valid implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the refs are the same, the API of your implementation is so misleading that's hard to argue with that guy. If you are using new to obtain your Singleton instance, you are doing it wrong.

Just take a look at this implementation:

```
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

function run() {

    var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    alert("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));  
}
```

It clearly expresses the intent of its author.